# redirect my site from www.foo.bar to cdn.foo.bar

Tags: .htaccess

is it possible to have an htaccess rule that will redirect my files from

`http://www.mydomain.com/page.html` to `http://cdn.mydomain.com/page.html` but still making the link look like `http://www.mydomain.com/page.html`

I know masking urls isn't possible, but since they are on the same domain i was wondering if that was possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# for http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://cdn.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R]

# for https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://cdn.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

However one caveat that it is an **external redirect** hence URL in your browser will change to `http://cdn.mydomain.com/foo` because when you are jumping from one host to another you cannot have **internal redirect** hence `R` flag is needed.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about .htaccess but you could use a curl script in PHP.